# From matrix of community co-occurences to the index of community for every node

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, cluster-analysis

I have an `n x n` matrix `X_{ij}` where the `i-j`-th entry is 1 if node `i` and node `j` in a graph belong to the same cluster and 0 otherwise. That matrix is a result of an optimization algorithm to find communities in a graph.

I want to transform that matrix in a list with `n` entries, where for every `i`-th entry I can associate an integer that represent the separate cluster that the `i`-th node belongs to.

For example, in python, my matrix is the following (in this case nodes 0 and 1 belong to community A, while nodes 2 and 3 belongs to community B)

```
matrix([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
    [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

that means that node 0 belong to the same community (nodes are from 0 to n-1)
How is possible to extract from that matrix a list like this:

```
[A,A,B,B]
```

where the i-th element of the list represent the index of the community the node belongs?
(I'm using A and B just for being more clear, but those indices are in fact integers)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that this relation is *symetric* (`X_{ij} = X_{ji}`) and *transitive* (`X_{ij} = 1, X_{jk}= = 1 -> X_{ik} = 1`)?

Comment: The matrix is a representation of a disconnected graph. You need to find the connected components. Scan through the matrix and perform a simple BFS or DFS. When you can't go further, take any of the remaining unscanned nodes

Comment: Yes, because the solution I get enforce the transitivity and symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this relation you have is [*symmetric*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation) (`X_{ij} = X_{ji}`) and [*transitive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) (`X_{ij} = 1, X_{jk}= = 1 -> X_{ik} = 1`), you can regard your matrix as a graph `G=(V,E)` where each index `i=1,...,n` is a node, and `(i,j)` is in `E` if and only if `X_{ij} = 1`.

So, your "communities" are actually *connected components* of the graph.

Finding connected components is fairly easy with any graph discovery/traversal algorithm such as [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) using the following high-level pseudo code:

```
X = V //all nodes initially in X
count = 1
while X is not empty:
   choose random x in X 
   do BFS from x, let the set of discovered nodes be U
   for each node u in U:
        yield (u,count) //u is in the community labeled as count
   count = count + 1
   X = X \ U //remove all nodes in U from X
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used networkx to get the connected components from the co occurence matrix and then iterated on the nodes in those connected components. That solved my day!